# How to do product listing in custom module page?

Tags: magento2, module

How to do product listing on custom module page?

I have tried but it prints array.

Comment: @MahalakshmiM  I tried coding from this link.

Comment: can u  provide that link

Comment: @MahalakshmiM http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-product-collection/

Answer (score 2):

In your block Class add product collection factory to you constructor

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
) {
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
}
```

Add getProductCollection method

```
public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
    return $collection;
}
```

If you want to filter products you can use addAttributeToFilter method.

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('yourAttributeName', 'YourAttributeValue']);
```

Then in your template file call getProductCollection method and iterates on returned object:

```
<?php $_products = $block->getProductCollection()->getItems(); ?>
<?php foreach ($_products as $_product): ?>
    <h1> <?php echo $_product->getName(); ?> </h1>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```